# connect to websocket with playwright

Tags: typescript, websocket, playwright

i want to connect to a WS but it retuns an error

this is my calling test

```
test(`connection`, async () => {
  const url = endpoint.webSocketURL;
  const authToken = authorizationValue;
  try {
    const websocket = await connectToWebSocket(url, authToken);
    expect(websocket.readyState,"Verify Trade Streaming connection").toBe(WebSocket.OPEN);
    websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const data = event.data;
      console.log('Received message: ', data);
    };

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("WebSocket connection failed: ", error);
  }
});
```

and this is my ws class

```
import { WebSocket } from 'ws';

export const connectToWebSocket = (url: string, authToken: string): Promise<WebSocket> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(url);

    ws.on('open', () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
      const authMessage = JSON.stringify({ token: authToken });
      ws.send(authMessage);
      resolve(ws);
    });

    ws.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log('Received message:', data);

    });

    ws.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error.message);
      reject(error);
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
    });
  });
};
```

it gives me an error
WebSocket connection established.
WebSocket connection failed:  ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using the 'ws' library. However, your test code is trying to use the native WebSocket object, which is not defined.

To fix this, you should import the WebSocket object from the 'ws' library in your test file, just like you did in your WebSocket class.